# How find a nth node value using ruby

Tags: ruby, json, api, parsing

I have a JSON response tree like structure

```
{
  "id":""
  "node": [
      {
        "id":""
        "node": [
              {
                "id":""
                "node":[] 
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

How could I get the last id value, it's just example it may contain n number of loops.

Answer (score 3):

```
h = {
  "id" => "1",
  "node" => [
    {
      "id" => "2",
      "node" => [
        {
          "id" => "3",
          "node" => []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


▶ λ = ->(h) { h['node'].empty? ? h['id'] : λ.(h['node'].last) }
#⇒ #<Proc:0x00000002f4b490@(pry):130 (lambda)>
▶ λ.(h)
#⇒ "3"
```

Comment: I know it's irrelevant but how can I type `λ`?

Comment: @Aetherus I use very custom keyboard layout on Linux, operated through xkb’s layouts in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`. MacOS/Windows ⚑ suck as operating systems.

Comment: @lurker Yeah, let’s live in XX century, type 10 chars instead of one most suitable here and most easy readable.

Comment: @mudasobwa I'll try it on my Elementary OS, and I can't agree more that Windows sucks. As for MacOS, I don't know because I haven't used it much.

Comment: @Aetherus google for “xkb customize layout” or like; do not forget to `include "level3(ralt_switch)"` and you’ll get ≈80 additional symbols of your choice typed in one key press for free :)

Comment: I believe that the FORTRAN language introduced the concept of single-character variables. So mid-20th century. ;) And using `λ` to define a lambda is cute, until you need to define two or more different lambdas, then do you call them `λ1` and `λ2` (harkening back to FORTRAN again)?

Comment: @lurker with single-letter vars one would quickly run out of free names for integers, as far as I remember :) Anyway, `λ` is a perfect example of good variable name, especially taking into account that `lambda` is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this method will helps you. You can call recursion method with sub hash.

```
h = {
  "id" => "1",
  "node" => [
    {
      "id" => "2",
      "node" => [
        {
          "id" => "3",
          "node" => []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

def get_last_node(h)
  if Array === h['node'] && !h['node'].empty?
    h['node'].each do |node_h|
      id = send(__callee__, node_h)
      return id if id
    end
    nil
  else
    h['id']
  end
end

get_last_node(h)
# => 3
```

Comment: Consider using `__callee__` instead of `__method__`, since the former returns alias names for aliases, while the latter returns the actual method name, even when called via an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @mudasobwa's answer:

```
def get_last_node(h)
  h["node"].empty? ? h["id"] : get_last_node(h["node"].first)
end

get_last_node(h)
  #=> 3
```